# Image is not drawing on top left of panel

Tags: java, graphics2d

When i load image ,it do not load at upper left (if the image is large to be fit on window size).This is because i diminish its size as shown in code. Although i am giving its coordinate value 0,0 it is not drawing at that position.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class photo extends JFrame 
{
Dimension screenwidth=getToolkit().getScreenSize();
int mx=(int)screenwidth.getWidth(); 
int my=(int)screenwidth.getHeight();
BufferedImage picture1;
JLabel label3;
int neww;
int newh;
    public photo() {

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Image Editor v1.0");
    f.setLayout(null);
    try{
        File file=new File("e:\\8.jpg");
            picture1=ImageIO.read(file);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout(null);
    panel2.setBounds(101,20,mx-100,my-20);
    f.add(panel2);
    label3 = new JLabel("");
    label3.setBounds(110,30,mx-110,my-30);
    panel2.add(label3);
    f.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    BufferedImage bi = null;

            if(picture1.getWidth()>mx-110 ||picture1.getHeight()>my-30 )
            {

                 neww= (int) Math.round(picture1.getWidth() * 0.25);
                newh = (int) Math.round(picture1.getHeight() *0.25);
            }
            else
            {
                neww=picture1.getWidth();
                newh=picture1.getHeight();

            }
            bi = new BufferedImage(neww,newh,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bi.createGraphics();
            g2d.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY));
            g2d.drawImage(picture1,0,0,neww,newh,0,0,picture1.getWidth(),picture1.getHeight(), null);
           label3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));

    }

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    new photo();

}

}
```

Comment: Could you give the details of `picture1` and `icon` variables.

Comment: neww=width after scaling,
newh=height after scaling,
picture1=image which is to be loaded on which operation will be done (i am developing image editor).

Comment: Did you dislay the neww and newh values to make sure that are not 0? If you need more help then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: checking ... @camickr

Comment: @camickr If the image is showing that means the `newh` and `neww` are not 0

Comment: @camickr :-please tell me if i am right. Last line says a blank space would create starting from 0,0 (i think this is not the coordinate of screen) to neww and newh.Then on that blank space a picture would be map from 0,0 (of picture coordinates) till its width height.....Here which method should be used to relocate the blank section ..i am not able to find out.

Comment: You haven't answered my question and you haven't posted a `SSCCE`, so I can't help. Good luck.

Comment: camickr- please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `g2d.translate(0, 0);` between `g2d.addRenderingHints` and `g2d.drawImage` and try it.

**EDIT**

So if you want the image to be at 101 px and 20 px, you should `label3.setBounds(0,0,neww,newh);` after `label3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));` instead of the current. I think this shall work as I have just tested.

Comment: its not working. .How to move that blank space so automatically on that section image will map

Comment: @user3763165 after seeing your edited post, I would like to ask you why are your are setting bounds of `panel2` and `label3` with `x` value `101` and `110` respectively as they would combined leave as space of `211` pixels in the left and wit `y` value `20` and `30` respectively as it would leave a combined 50 pixels from the top.

Comment: @Blip- Above is just a part of my program ,other side their are buttons for different functions

Comment: @user3763165 ok but my question is it is leaving more than 211 pixel in the left?

Comment: @Blip- 211pixel for different functionality (diff panel)but i want the image to be loaded at from 101,20 how should i do that.How to translate??

Comment: @user3763165 Why I asked you this question is that when I recreated this program in my system, I got the picture at the left when I set the `x`  to 0 for bounds of for `label3` and `panel2`.

Comment: @Blip-its right because image will bound at 0,0 but if you take a picture of large width and height it will not map on that but below check out for big image

Comment: ok wait i am checking.. internet is disconnecting :P would  reply late